# Linked list appears backwards

Tags: c, list, loops, struct, linked-list

I have a linked list that is coming out backwards. I appear to be adding elements to the back of the list, when I want to place them on the front.
My nodes appear as follows:

```
struct node{
int data;
struct node* next;};
```

Next I set the head and variables

```
int info,x,listLength;
struct node *head = NULL;
struct node *temp;
printf("How many nodes?\n");
scanf("%d",&listLength);
```

Now I prompt for a new entry in the list, and move along the nodes

```
    for(x=1;x<=listLength;x++){
    printf("Insert an X value for node %d\n",x);
    scanf("%d",&info);
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = info;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

Finally I output the results and free the memory space

```
    while(temp!=NULL){
    printf("WE GOT %d\n",temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
}
free(temp);
```

However, if I enter input for three nodes and enter 1,2 and then 3, the output is 3,2, then 1! How can I change this to make sure the nodes are being added to the right place?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're inserting nodes at the head of the list - if you want to keep the same order then you need to append them to the tail of the list.

Comment: Actually, you *are* putting new elements at the front of the list. That's why they end up in reverse order (think about it and maybe walk through a simulation on paper). If you want them in the list in the same order as you add them, then you need to add them to the end of the list, which will require either a more complex list structure (with an end pointer and maybe some sort of back link depending on how you might want to manipulate the items on the list) or you'll have to walk the list to find the end node to add the new node after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is saying

```
temp->next = head;
head = temp;
```

So you are adding to the start of the list, not the end, so "reverse order" is correct.
To add to the end you either need to keep track of the last node you added (e.g. `struct node tail`), or you need to search from head through the next ptrs until next = null to find where to add the new node.

Also: why the `free(temp)` at the end? Since it is after `while(temp != NULL)` it means temp must equal null. Are you trying to free the whole list or what?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is adding to the start of a list considered bad practice?

Comment: Depends what you are using the list for - if order "means something" then it has to be right. If it's just a collection of stuff (more like a set than a list) then order doesn't matter and so adding to the front is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `head` pointer points to the last object, thats why you get the numbers 'backwards'.

input: 1, 2, 3

head[data: 3] (last thing `temp` pointed to) -> next[data: 2] -> next[data: 1] -> NULL

Answer (score 0):

it is working correctly..you want to put new node in front of the list, right? after 1, you are adding so. so now the list will be: 2->1, and in the same way, 3->2->1